# Flashplugin works on youtube but not on website I belong to to watch training videos

Tags: firefox, flash

I can watch video on Youtube with the flash-plugin, but I cannot watch video on a training website that charges monthly for access. I was able to watch video on that site before I switched to Ubuntu last week. Hope someone has the answer for me... many thanks.

Comment: have you tried with another browser? i.e. Chrome or Chromium?

Comment: How did you install the flash plugin? Do you get any particular Error messages? What does the browser say when you try to play video on that site? Also, make sure the youtube player doesn't say "HTML5" in the bottom right, which would mean it's not flash at all that's playing the video. Thank you for providing that information, you can edit your question to add it by clicking the 'edit' link right beneath the tags.

Comment: This sort of issue usually stems from poor Flash detection code on websites. I would certainly refer this issue to their technical support -- especially as you're paying for it.

Comment: Are you in 32-bit or 64-bit? The latter is... Less pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

Often this can be caused by conflicting flash plugins. YouTube works with most of the Free software alternatives to Flash, but many other custom video players do not.

Make sure you've removed any of the browser plugin components of any other players (`browser-plugin-gnash`, for example), so that the non-free plugin is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Get my [Flash-Aid](http://www.webgapps.org/addons/flash-aid) (version 2.0) extension for Firefox. It will detect the best flash version for your system and install it. It also removes conflicting plugins if you have any and apply some performance tweaks.

If you are unable to run flash on the site after using Flash-Aid, go to the extension Help tab, click the report button and send me the results so I can analise your situation.